# Simulink S-Function Builder only allows for 1-D & 2-D dimension. How to select 3-D for RGB image?

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink

I am looking to pass an RGB image through an s function block. I can easily do this with a greyscale image as it is 2-D but there doesnt seem to be the option of selecting a 3-D dimension for RGB images.

[image]

How can this be achieved using the s-function builder block?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is trying to do something similar, I was able to modify the C++ source code that the S-Function builder was outputting to pass a 3D array through the blocks IO.

Steps I took:

- Update the ssSetInputPortDimensionInfo to take in a 3D array.
- Set the ssSetInputPortDimensionInfo.width to be the total number of elements.
- Comment the line ssSetInputPortMatrixDimensions.
- Repeat the steps above for the Output Port.